# raspbmc Tag - separate tag or synonym for xbmc?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just tagged the question about raspbmc with a new tag for raspbmc: [Why does Raspbmc hang randomly?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/raspbmc-hangs-randomly)

It was already tagged with xbmc, but I figure there's room for either a specific tag, or at least a synonym for raspbmc as it relates to specifically to the RPi.

(The edit may still be pending).

Comment: Agreed. Don't think this needs discussion, just suggest the edit and it will get approved (or not).

Comment: Have suggested - making sure it doesn't get rejected out of hand because its a new tag.

Answer (score 1):

A new tag is a good idea, because Raspbmc is a separate distribution. Questions tagged with [xmbc](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xmbc) should be about XMBC on other distributions.

Comment: Ah right - didn't realise it was separate enough - sort of just though that raspbmc was the only version of xbmc we'd see on the RPi.

Comment: @JonEgerton My understanding of it is that Raspbmc is just a nice wrap up of Debian and XBMC.

Comment: I don't think "Questions tagged with xmbc should _be about XMBC on other distributions_" Rather they should concern _using_ the application, in contrast to installing a distribution (like raspbmc or openelec) or installing xbmc in a distribution